# Google Adwords convertion tracking in Magento not visible in View Source

Tags: magento

I have installed google adwords tracking on the success.phtml

I am able to track conversion but I am not sure if all conversions are tracked properly. Our payment methods are Paypal Express and Paypal Payment pro where customer pay via credit card on our website. This ensures that every customer hits the success page.

However when I complete the order and check the conversion page source (View Source) I am not able to see the Google conversion tracking code.

Is it normal that in view source the Google conversion tracking code is not visible yet?

Regards,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get to the success page it is displayed. Once you hit view source you are actually making another request to the success page so it technically reloads it. At that point the code is not displayed again because the transaction was already completed (if that worked you could reload the page and track transactions over and over again).

To check to make sure it shows up correctly do an inspect element in chrome or firefox/firebug to see if the code is on the page.